# Why does conn.Read() write nothing into a []byte, but bufio.Reader.ReadString() works?

Tags: go, connection, bufferedreader, reader

I have a connection, created like this:

```
conn, err = net.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:20000")
```

I have tried reading from this connection in two ways. I think they both must work, but the first option doesn't.

Here is the first way of doing it:

```
var bytes []byte
for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
    conn.Read(bytes)
}
fmt.Printf("%v", bytes)
```

The output of this method is:

```
[]
```

And here is the same thing, done with `bufio.Reader`:

```
func readResponse(conn net.Conn) (response string, err error) {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(conn)
    _, err = reader.Discard(8)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    response, err = reader.ReadString('\n')

    return
}
```

This function returns the response given by the server on the other end of the TCP connection.

Why does `bufio.Reader.Read()` work, but `net.Conn.Read()` doesn't?

Comment: Well, that is dead obvious: `Read` reads **into** the provided `[]byte`. Your `[]byte` is empty, it has zero length and this whole zero length is filled. So technically your `Read`call worked as it completely filled the provided byte slice with data from the connection. You took the Tour of Go?

Comment: Thanks. I am new to a lot of the concepts, so some things I read in the tour or the first time I look at the documentation of a function goes over my head without me realizing it. Sorry for the irritation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [`Conn.Read()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Conn) method is to implement [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader), the general interface to read data from any source of bytes into a `[]byte`. Quoting from the doc of `Reader.Read()`:

> Read reads up to len(p) bytes into p.

So `Read()` reads up to `len(p)` bytes but since you pass a `nil` slice, it won't read anything (length of a `nil` slice is `0`). Please read the linked doc to know how `Reader.Read()` works.

`Reader.Read()` does not allocate a buffer (`[]byte`) where the read data will be stored, you have to create one and pass it, e.g.:

```
var buf = make([]byte, 100)
n, err := conn.Read(buf)
// n is the number of read bytes; don't forget to check err!
```

Don't forget to always check the returned `error` which may be `io.EOF` if end of data is reached. The general contract of `io.Reader.Read()` also allows returning some non-`nil` error (including `io.EOF`) and some read data (`n > 0`) *at the same time*. The number of read bytes will be in `n`, which means only the first `n` bytes of the `buf` is useful (in other words: `buf[:n]`).

Your other example using [`bufio.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader) works because you called [`Reader.ReadString()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadString) which doesn't require a `[]byte` argument. If you would've used the [`bufio.Reader.Read()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.Read) method, you would also had to pass a non-`nil` slice in order to actually get some data.

Comment: I'd also note that novices often get tripped by a false expectation of `Read()` reading exactly so much data to fill the whole slice. The "problem" is in those "up to" words in the documentation string which actually stand to mean "any number of bytes between 1 and the length of the input buffer". To fill the whole buffer, one should use [`io.ReadFull()`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadFull). This behaviour follows the semantics of the [`read()` syscall of POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/read.html).